# Killing zombies with weapons in Die2Nite

Tags: die2nite

How do weapons work in Die2Nite? I'm interested in the game mechanics, the manual is a bit terse on that point.

- Do you need APs to kill zombies with them?
- How many zombies can you kill with one?
- How do weapons differ from each other?
- Which weapons are effective, and which should I ignore?
- What are the risks of attacking zombies with weapons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Do you need APs to kill zombies with them?     *No. Caveat: There are town-based weapons that require AP to fire out of the town,but personal weapons are fired at no AP cost.*
- How many zombies can you kill with one? *It varies; some 1 only, some more than one. I think there is a random element with some weapons.*
- How do weapons differ from each other? *I think each have a probability of a successful attack, a probability of failing/breaking and a quasi-random element of damage (i.e. you may kill more or less Zs with similar attacks)*
- Which weapons are effective, and which should I ignore? ***The $64k question***. The most devastating weapons costs more in terms of resources - resources that may be better used elsewhere. In my limited experienced, the weapons are fairly well-balanced - I haven't discovered a preferred weapon yet.
- What are the risks of attacking zombies with weapons? ***There is a very serious risk that one or more zombies will get hurt!*** In reality, you won't used weapons until as a last resort when you are trapped. I've never been injured while attacking with a weapon, but I imagine it is possible with certain weapons, but unlike hand-to-hand, I suspect the probability is very low.

Comment: I'm almost positive it costs 1 AP to attack a zombie.

Comment: Also, you can only become injured by fleeing, not by attacking.

Answer (score 6):

I wish I had a complete answer, but by far the most efficient way to do some hardcore zombie cleansing is:

- liberal amounts of **water pistols** (three shots each, maximum), and
- the **Plumbing** epic project, under Foundations, that allows us to refill water based weapons for *free.*

We're killing an average of 80 zombies per day since we built plumbing, all for practically free :)

> [image: So many zombies, so little time...]
>
> *This is our map in day 12. Refreshingly zombie free.*

Before that the most powerful use of water based weapons may be the **water bomb**: a plastic bag filled with water with Semtex strapped onto it — costly, but useful when clearing out buildings (~6 kills per bomb).

Comment: Your AP costs may vary, however... especially with Watchtower 4 and 5.

Comment: I used the Exploding Water Bomb once (before I knew how expensive it was to make). Trapped by 8 zombies, it only cleared 4.... I was gutted.

Comment: @CJM I'm not a scavenger myself, so I'm not in first line against zombies; I usually earn my water rations with constructionery things :)

Comment: Wow, that's impressive.  Our entire map looks like the upper right-hand corner.

Comment: I've yet to come that far as to actually build one of the big projects, and this game the random number generator really hates us.

Comment: @Fabian 130 AP aren't that hard to gather... That said, our town does have an awful lot of heroes.

Comment: We have 2 Heroes, most of the players are new, it is the second day and the expected attack is 135-155 zombies. To add to that we didn't find a single "Handful of Nuts and Bolts" yet. I somehow don't think we'll be building the Plumbing project in this game. But at some point I'd really like to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
Do you need APs to kill zombies with them?
```

Short answer, no.  There are no weapons in the game that require AP to use them.  There is no such thing as a weapon that fires from town that costs AP! (at least not in our version of the game)

```
How many zombies can you kill with one?
```

The results vary depending on the weapon.  There is such a massive array of weapons it would be too time consuming and lengthy to list them all.  The best option if you find a weapon you are unsure of is to ask somebody in town or get a hero from your town to ask on the world forum.  Never build a weapon you are unsure of, especially if it uses up any of the rarer materials!

```
How do weapons differ from each other?
```

The number of kills vary, the materials required to build the weapon can vary, and the items used as ammunition also vary (if they need any ammunition at all!)

```
Which weapons are effective, and which should I ignore?
```

As one of the previous questions, there are so so many weaopons its hard to list them all, if you dont know about a weapon then ask somebody.

```
What are the risks of attacking zombies with weapons?
```

There are no risks at all. If you attack a zombie using a weapon you will never be hurt in the process.